# Named query when property is an object?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, named-query

I would like to make this query in JPA:

```
SELECT * FROM `happyDB`.`users` U WHERE U.party_as_user =1 AND U.party_party_id =2
```

This is working fine, but my problem is that I have `Party` only as an object, not as an id and I can't make it work.

In the `Users`-entity where I am trying to do the named query I have the following:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "pary_party_id", referencedColumnName = "party_id")
@ManyToOne
private Party partyId;

@Column(name = "party_as_user")
private Boolean partyAsUser;
```

I tried to implement it like an object with dot notation, but that's not working:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByPartyAsUser", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.partyAsUser = :partyAsUser AND u.partyId.partyId = :partyId")
```

There is a property called `partyId` inside the `Party`-object, but it's not working. Is there any solution for that or do I have to add one property to the Users-bean like `private int partyID` and populate it every time when a new `Party` is inserted into `Users`?

Thanks for helping!
Sami Nurmi

Comment: What error do you get?  Perhaps include your Party class.  In general calling the relationship party, instead of partyId would make sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general you can use an object as a parameter in JPA,

```
SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.partyAsUser = :partyAsUser AND u.party  = :party

Party party = new Party(id);
query.setParameter("party", party);
```

But what you have should work if you use the correct variable names, my guess is,

```
SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.partyAsUser = :partyAsUser AND u.party.id  = :id
```

And you can always use a native SQL query, if you understand SQL better than objects.

Comment: That was my mistake, I don't even need that id, just object. It just was a stupid mistake :( THANKS!